# Error when fetching Amadeus locations with reference-data.locations using non english keywords

Tags: amadeus

This API of the Amadeus SDK works fine only when submitting requests using english characters. For example using the following will be ok:

{ subType: 'CITY', keyword: 'beijing'}

However, when using the actual chinese characters for Beijing, we'll get an error instead:

{ subType: 'CITY', keyword: '北京'}.

What kind of encoding should we use, or does Amadeus simply not support foreign language keywords?

Answer (score 0):

The APIs support Latin characters and mostly the English language, unless there is a `lang` parameter in APIs like the [Hotel Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference) which can return content in another language.

Comment: Thanks, we've decided to simply use Apple's CLGeocoder sdk for location searches.